# is there a workaround for subpixel borders with full sized inner divs in chrome 61?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

EDIT: It has been verified that it is a bug in 61 that they will fix before 62 goes stable https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=763402

With the latest chrome update I have seen some of my subpixel borders go missing on two sides. Which sides they are is inconsistent. I have boiled the issue down to this

```
<pre>
legend:
    pink: 1px border inner uses 100px//no problem
    salmon: .5px border inner uses 99% //no problem
    orange: .5px border inner uses 99px //no problem
    blue: .5px border inner uses 100% //missing borders consistant sides
    green: .5px border inner uses 100px //missing borders consistant sides
</pre>

<div style="border:solid 1px black; width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background:lightpink"> </div>
</div>

<br />

<div style="border:solid .5px black; width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div style="width:99%; height:99%; background:salmon"></div>
</div>

<br />

<div style="border:solid .5px black; width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div style="width:99px; height:99px; background:orange"></div>
</div>

<br />

<div style="border:solid .5px black; width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background:lightblue"></div>
</div>


<br />

<div style="border:solid .5px black; width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background:lightgreen"></div>
</div>

<br />

<div style="border:solid .5px black; width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background:lightgreen"></div>
</div>

<br />

<div style="border:solid .5px black; width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background:lightgreen"></div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/arrowplum/qmvx8obn/

Does anyone see where I may be doing something incorrect? If not, is there a workaround?

Note that these examples are fine in Chrome 60, safari and firefox

Here is a screenshot if you are fiddle allergic: 
[image: subpixel screenshot]

EDIT: @brian17han added a workaround that does work for chrome but then breaks safari and firefox https://jsfiddle.net/arrowplum/qt0m7f2p/

[image: brian17than fix on safari]

EDIT2: modifying the padding to .1px then works for safari, chrome, and firefox with the exception of firefox on retina displays which shows a half pixel space between the inner and outer.
[image: Firefox retina]

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the problematic view? and what is your Chrome version?

Comment: chrome 61, chromium 63 sure I can screenshot the jsfiddle if you want

Comment: I just upgraded my Chrome to 61 and I see what you are saying. It's very weird. Are you looking for a solution or a reason? I can provide a solution but I have no idea why this is happening. And I'm scared about what is going to happen to my own site. @joem

Comment: I am looking for a solution, and am very curious about a reason ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason Chrome 61 behaves differently than the older version is unclear to me.

However, here is a quick solution. You can add `padding` to your container and set the `padding` to the same size as your `border-width`.
If you want your container's `width` and `height` to be `100px` **with the border**, you will need to set your container to be `box-sizing: border-box;`. Otherwise, your container size will be `100px` + `border-width`.

**EDITED**: I added another solution which uses `box-shadow: inset` to simulate the border.

```css
div.padding-container {
  border: solid .5px black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: .5px;
}

div.padding-container div.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

div.with-inner-border {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  
  padding: 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding-container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="with-inner-border">
<div><p>hdafsljkdfs jklasdf jl kads  jlk afsd jklfsad l jkfdsa ljkas</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks fine on chrome but not fine on safari. https://jsfiddle.net/arrowplum/qt0m7f2p/

Comment: If you change to .1px instead of .5px it works on safari (I assume it rounds down in this case) and on firefox on regular displays, _however_ on retina displays in firefox you see a white border between the inner and the outer https://jsfiddle.net/arrowplum/qt0m7f2p/2/

Comment: I added another solution which uses `box-shadow: inset` to simulate the border. Please let me know if this solution is valid for you. @joem

Comment: unfortunately this also has issues on safari (when you have an inner div) depending on zoom level @brian17han

Comment: @joem the second `box-shadow: inset` solutions works fine for me in Safari, I do have an inner div. Could you elaborate more about the issue?

Comment: The second box (the yellow one) that you added has a 1px border not a .5px border. 1px has always worked even with border, @brian17han.